# Can Crystal calculate a Running Total for suppressed rows?

Tags: crystal-reports, cumulative-sum

My Crystal Report does the following:

[image]

The report displays data for one month, which is selected using the runtime parameter {?ReportDate}. Data for the other months available in the database is hidden by suppressing the Details section for all months except the selected one. The report displays the selected month's Popsicle and Soda sales, estimated (budgeted) Popsicle and Soda sales for the selected month, prior year sales, Year to Date (YTD) sales, Last 12 Month (LTM) sales, and an estimate of sales for the full calendar year.

The prior year, YTD, and LTM values are correctly calculated using Running Totals. However, the Running Total used to calculate the estimated sales for the calendar year is only calculated correctly if I display the selected month along with the remaining months of the year.

Here are the relevant Running Total Evaluation formulas and the Suppression condition:

Details section suppression condition:

```
DateValue ({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) <> {?ReportDate}
```

Running Total evaluation formulas:

Prior Year:

```
DateValue({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) = DateAdd("yyyy", -1, {?ReportDate})
```

YTD:

```
DateValue({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) >= DateValue(Year({?ReportDate}), 1, 1) AND DateValue({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) <= {?ReportDate}
```

LTM:

```
DateValue({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) >= DateAdd ("m", -11 , {?ReportDate}) AND DateValue({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) <= {?ReportDate}
```

*Budgeted Sales for remainder of year:

```
DateValue({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) <= DateValue(Year({?ReportDate}), 12, 31) AND DateValue({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) > {?ReportDate}
```

*This Running Total only works if I change the Details section suppression condition to: `DateValue ({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) < {?ReportDate}`, which displays the selected month along with the remaining months of the year. Otherwise, the Running Total returns null.

Is there a way to calculate this Running Total without displaying the other months of the year?

Comment: ReportDate looks like parameter what are you passing during runtime and what is your supression condition?

Comment: Yes, ReportDate is a runtime parameter that identifies the month to display in the report. The formula used to suppress the Details section for all of other months is "DateValue ({vw_CommonDates.CommonDate}) <> {?ReportDate}".